# How can I show a back arrow in the master-view popover button for UISplitViewController in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

In my detail VC, I am implementing this UISplitViewController delegate method:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController*)pc
```

It is then easy for me to set the title of the button, but the result is just a button with plain text, and no back arrow. I am looking to get something like the Mail app where the master popover button also has the back chevron.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your custom bar button item, with the chevron image, set up as you want, and set the target and action of your bar button item to be that of the one passed by the delegate callback. This way, your bar button will perform the same action as the one the system passes to you. You must create your own bar button with an image, because there is no possible way with AppStore approved API to create back bar buttons.

In iOS7, the private subclasses are `UINavigationItemView` + `_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView`. One is the button, the other - the chevron. `_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView` is a subclass of `UIImageView`. So it's pretty close to what you will achieve.

Comment: Interesting. So do you think the Mail app is using an image in their back button?

Comment: The mail app has access to APIs you don't. There are private subclasses which Apple uses normally for back bar buttons. In the mail app, it is more than likely they use those, rather than fake it.

Comment: I checked. In iOS7, the private subclasses are `UINavigationItemView` + `_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView`. One is the button, the other - the chevron. `_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView` is a subclass of `UIImageView`. So it's pretty close to what you will achieve.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 8, UISplitViewController has a method:

```
- (UIBarButtonItem *)displayModeButtonItem
```

If you set the returned bar button item as the left button of a navigation bar (UINavigationBar), it will display the chevron for you.

On the other hand, if you put the returned bar button item into a toolbar (UIToolbar), it will not display the chevron.

For places where I want the chevron back button shown, but also need several of my own bar button items shown (like the Mail app on iPad does), I have to use a UINavigationBar and a UIToolbar. It's an ugly solution, but I have to partially overlay the UINavigationBar on top of the UIToolbar in order to get a back button chevron along with several of my own bar button items.

Answer (score 0):

To access the default back button image used by Apple as what Leo said, the arrow is a class of type _UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView. Set this image to a back bar button and you are good to go.

Here follows the hack,

```
        UIImage *imgViewBack ;

        for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
            // The arrow is a class of type _UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView. This is not any of the private methods, so I think
            // this is fine for the AppStore...
            if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:@"_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView"]) {
                // Set the image from the Default BackBtn Imageview
                UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *) view;
                if(imgView){
                    imgViewBack = imgView.image ;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is based on Ryan Henning's answer.

It's possible to show a back button representing the master view from the detail view controller. The UISplitview controller doesn't provide a native method for this, but it returns a bar button object which we can directly assign as navigation controller bar button. Its obvious that the detail view controller should be inside a navigation controller for this to work.

```
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
```